# How to show the icons based on the click function in react js

Tags: reactjs

This is one of the component

```
const [mic, setMic] = useState(false)

const micClick = () => {
  setMic(true)
 alert('micClicked',mic)
}

<VideoControls
   micClick={micClick}
/>
```

this is other component

```
 const VideoControls = ({ 
   micClick,
 }) => {

 return (
    <Card style={style} className={classes.root}>
      <Button>
        <MicIcon style={iconStyle} onClick={micClick} />
      </Button>
      <Button>
         <MicOffIcon style={iconStyle} onClick={micClick} />
    </Button>
  }
```

I want to show the `MicIcon` as a default whenever button is clicked i want to change it as `MicOffIcon` , but here i dont have any idea how to utilize it. please help me thanks in advance

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a mic state you can pass it down and then based on that state render whatever icon you feel like, as example:

```
const [mic, setMic] = useState(false)

const micClick = () => {
  setMic(true)
 alert('micClicked',mic)
}
<VideoControls
   micClick={micClick}
   mic={mic}
/>
```

and then inside your VideoControls component:

```
const VideoControls = ({ 
   micClick,
   mic
 }) => {

 return (
    <Card style={style} className={classes.root}>
      <Button>
         {mic ? 
        <MicIcon style={iconStyle} onClick={micClick} /> : 
        <YourOtherIcon/> }
      </Button>
      <Button>
         <MicOffIcon style={iconStyle} onClick={micClick} />
    </Button>
  }

<VideoControls
   micClick={micClick}
   mic={mic}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `mic` as a prop to your `VideoControls` component. And set your icons according to the value of `mic`.

```
const [mic, setMic] = useState(false)

const micClick = () => {
  setMic(mic => !mic); // change the value of mic 
  alert('micClicked',!mic)
}

<VideoControls
   micClick={micClick}
   mic={mic}
/>
```

**VideoControls Component**

```
 const VideoControls = ({ 
   micClick, mic
 }) => {

 return (
    <Card style={style} className={classes.root}>
      {mic ? 
      <Button>
        <MicIcon style={iconStyle} onClick={micClick} />
      </Button>
       :
      <Button>
         <MicOffIcon style={iconStyle} onClick={micClick} />
      </Button>
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass your `mic` state variable to the VideoControls component and display the relevant Icon based on its value:

```
<VideoControls
   micClick={micClick}
   mic={mic}
/>
```

and

```
 const VideoControls = ({ 
   micClick,
   mic
 }) => {

 return (
    <Card style={style} className={classes.root}>
      <Button>
        {mic ? 
          <MicIcon style={iconStyle} onClick={micClick} /> :
          <MicOffIcon style={iconStyle} onClick={micClick} />
        }
      </Button>
    </Card>
 );
```